# About Wronkian and Able' s identity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

I want to what is the condition on $p_1$??

And I want to ask is the wronkian of any 2 fundamental solutions totally depends on $p_1$??

Because any fundamental solutions can be different from a multiplicative constant??(eg $3y_1$ and $8y_1$)

If not ,The wronkian is given by $W(t)$=$W(t_0)$ $exp$($-\lmoustache$$p_1$$dt$)

Then how to determine $W(t_0)$ if the wronkian of any 2 fundamental solutions IS NOT totally depends on $p_1$??